# How do add Log4j to maven project with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, pom.xml

I have a project that uses springboot, but mvn can't find any log4j-api although I included it in the dependencies. I want to know what is the proper way of adding it, here is the error msg I get for 'mvn install':

"Failure to find org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api-java9:pom:2.13.3 in https://devtools.jahia.com/nexus/content/repositories/jahia-releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of archetype has elapsed or updates are forced"

My pom.xml uses dependency manager for spring boot, because I have a different parent:

Thank you for your replies

Comment: May be your workspace and the system are using conflicting maven versions. Check in your C:\Users\*\.m2\wrapper\dists whether you have only 1 bin folder. If not delete one and correct your maven settings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I actually have only 1 bin folder

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Add some explanation for this dependency

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed ...Thanks anyways

Comment: Have you solved your problem?Can look your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer. But springboot uses commons logging by default and if you want to change it, you need to specifically exclude springboot-starter-logging and add log4j2 dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>``
```

Full doc:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging.log4j

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.